# Spivakovski-Popescu-Neron desingularisation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-representations, resolution-of-singularities

For $A \colon= {\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,...,X_d]]$, by generalising Popescu-Neron's method, Spivakovski proved that $A$ is written by smooth sub-algebras. That is,

$A \cong \underset{\lambda \in \Lambda}{\varinjlim}\,A_{\lambda}$,

where each $A_{\lambda} \subset A$ is a smooth sub-algebra of $A$ (i.e., $A_{\lambda}$ is a finitely generated smooth ${\Bbb F}_p$-algebra).

### Q. Is the inclusion $\iota_{\mu \lambda} \colon A_{\lambda} \hookrightarrow A_{\mu}$ flat, whenever $\iota_{\mu \lambda}$ exists?

I expect that such miracle should occur for the formal power series ring $A$. Please help me.

Comment: No, and injectivity of transition maps isn't generally true.  Suppose there were injective flat transition maps with $d=1$.  Localizing throughout by the contraction of the maximal ideal of $A=\mathbf{F}_p[\![x]\!]$ (so $A_{\lambda}$ become just "essentially of finite type") would make the transition maps local, so faithfully flat, so (for large $\lambda$) the $A_{\lambda}$ would be "algebraic" local rings of dimension 1. Thus, the transition maps would be eventually *algebraic* (by trdeg reasons), so ${\rm{Frac}}(A)$ would have trdeg 1 over $\mathbf{F}_p$, which is false.

Comment: Why algebraic local ring is dimension one? It could be infinite. Actually there are infinite algebraically independent elements in ${\Bbb F}_p[[X]]$.

Comment: A direct limit of flat local maps is a flat local map, hence faithfully flat.  Thus, if what you request were to happen then the maps from $A_{\lambda}$ to $A = \mathbf{F}_p[\![x]\!]$ would be faithfully flat, forcing each $A_{\lambda}$ to be noetherian and regular of dimension at most 1, so a field or dvr.  But the limit $A$ isn't a field, so for large $\lambda$ necessarily $A_{\lambda}$ is a dvr, and then by trdeg considerations the fraction field extensions among the $A_{\lambda}$'s would have to be algebraic, whence that of the limit $A$ is algebraic over those too, so contradiction.

Comment: Why "forcing each Aλ to be noetherian and regular of dimension at most 1"? I cannot understand this. Any dimensional noetherian geometric local ring can be embedded into ${\Bbb F}_p[[X]]$. As far as I remember, Spivakovski claimed that it is possible to write ${\Bbb F}_p[[X]]$ as the inductive limit of smooth (local) sub-algebras over ${\Bbb F}_p$.

Comment: These are not just embeddings: they are flat. This is the whole point of your question, the flatness property!  It is a general fact in commutative algebra that if a map of commutative rings is faithfully flat (e.g., local and flat) and the target is noetherian (resp. regular) then so is the source.   So what I have provided really is a counterexample to your question (and anyway, the methods of Artin, Popescu, etc. never provide injectivity for the transition maps, but that isn't as elementary to contradict as flatness).

Comment: As far as I checked, Spivakovsky proved that for the special case of a power series ring A, it is possible to take a family of sub-algebras of A such that each is smooth over $K$ and moreover the filtered inductive limit of them again make $A$.

Comment: I have explained why the answer to your flatness question is negative (even without the injectivity property assumed), so that is the end of the matter as far as this question is concerned.  (I am not familiar with Spivakovsky's paper; the works of Artin and Popescu do not provide inductive limits of smooth algebras with injective transition maps.)